# How to add an exception or manage the error at the following node function?

Tags: node.js

Here is my original code:

```
function extract_number(conv){
    const regex = /(?:(\+?\d{1,3}) )?(?:([\(]?\d+[\)]?)[ -])?(\d{1,5}[\- ]?\d{1,5})/
    const result = conv.match(regex)
    const value = result[0]
    console.log(value);
    return value
}
```

However it is falling with the string does not contains a number to extract
here the example:

```
extract_number('my number is')
```

I tried to catch the error as follows:

```
function extract_number(err,conv){
    if (err) {
        const regex = /(?:(\+?\d{1,3}) )?(?:([\(]?\d+[\)]?)[ -])?(\d{1,5}[\- ]?\d{1,5})/
        const result = conv.match(regex)
        const value = result[0]
        console.error('There was an error', err);
    }
        console.log(value)
        return value
}
```

I got:

/home/adolfo/node_js/index.js:61
        const result = conv.match(regex)
                            ^

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
    at extract_number (/home/adolfo/node_js/index.js:61:29)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/adolfo/node_js/index.js:69:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
```

at the seccond function, so I would like to appeciate support with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try..catch is your friend

```
function extract_number(conv){
   try{

      const regex = /(?:(\+?\d{1,3}) )?(?:([\(]?\d+[\)]?)[ -])?(\d{1,5}[\- ]?\d{1,5})/
    const result = conv.match(regex)
    const value = result[0]
    console.log(value);
    return value

     }catch(){
        return null

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's different approaches. You can do several checks on `result` on it's length or if it is type `Array`, and/or if `conv` is `null` or `undefined` and have that throw your error. Or you can implement a try/catch as specified [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch), which is probably the easiest way to accomplish what you're trying to do.

```
function extract_number(conv){
  const regex = /(?:(\+?\d{1,3}) )?(?:([\(]?\d+[\)]?)[ -])?(\d{1,5}[\- ]?\d{1,5})/
  let value;
  try {
    const result = conv.match(regex)
    value = result[0]
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('There was an error', err);
  }
    console.log(value);
    return value
}
```